# Ember.js v2 Load multiple models in route without making separate requests

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-data, models

Just getting started with Ember.js, so after a workign myself through the various tutorials online for a couple of weeks(…), I really can't puzzle out the following question.

**I want to display 4 models on 1 route. How can I do that, while avoiding making 4 server calls?**

More inforamtion:

I want to display records of type "person", "quote", "product" and "case" on my index page.

In my index route, (**routes/index.js**) I can load them using:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      persons : this.get('store').findAll('person'),
      quotes  : this.get('store').findAll('quote'),
      cases   : this.get('store').findAll('case'),
      products: this.get('store').findAll('product')
    });
  }
});
```

(And in my adapter, adapters/application.js, I have: )

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  host       : 'http://localhost:8080/dummy.php',
  pathForType: function (type) {
    return "?type=" + type;
  }
});
```

This works very nicely :), but ember.js makes 4 requests:

[image]

However, I could easily provide a JSON file that provides records of all 4 types.

So, how can I tell ember.js:

> "Here's a nice large JSON file, full of records. Now, use only records
>   of the 'person'-type for the person model, and idem dito for 'case',
>   'quote' and 'product'

?

Comment: You can [sideload](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes) data.

Comment: @Lux Thanks. Even when the 4 diffrent (kinds of) records are not related? In my case, the persons are not the authors, for example.

Comment: well.. you *are* literally making 4 requests. You should make an endpoint in your backend taking multiple values for type (send an array of types) and it sends back this big json with multiple data types and then you have to work your adapter/serializer to process the response

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Thanks. Now I know where to look further...

Comment: @Ideogram I haven't done much php in my life, but look for a JSON API-compliant serializer. It should solve some of these problems in a different way, which is more manageable

Comment: I would also agree for [sideloading](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes) the data, as they seem to have relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong in loading model per request. If models are related then you should consider defining [relationship](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/models/relationships/) between them. again for loading any async data it will make network request.

If you want to load data in single request for different model type, then you can try the below, this is not ember-data way. so I will not encourage this.

```
import Ember from "ember";

const {RSVP} = Ember;

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return RSVP
      .resolve(Ember.$.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/dummy.php'))
      .then((result) => {
        this.get('store').pushPayload(result);
        return {
          persons : this.get('store').peekAll('person'),
          quotes  : this.get('store').peekAll('quote'),
          cases   : this.get('store').peekAll('case'),
          products: this.get('store').peekAll('product')
        };
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: The more I investigate the issue, the more I feel your first sentence is crucial and is the actual answer.

Comment: I would love to mark this as the answer, but I can't get it working. (And I really tried). 

I keep on getting an error in the console: this.get(...).pushPayLoad is not a function. 

( Also, I needed to add “Ember” before the $ and an extra semicolumn to make jslint stop fuzzing. )

Comment: Oh sorry that's [`pushPayload`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushPayload) not `pushPayLoad`

Comment: Lowercase vs. uppercase,... oh my.... :) Edited your answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you probably could implement this in your adapter. This could give you some idea what you could do:

```
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('toLoad', {});
  },

  loadDebounces() {
    const toLoad = this.get('toLoad');
    this.set('toLoad', {});
    const keys = Object.keys(toLoad);

    const data = magicLoadForAllAllKeys(); // just do something you like here. Sent the keys as POST, or GET array, websockets, smoke signals..
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
      toLoad[key].resolve(data[key]);
    });
  },

  findAll (store, type, sinceToken, snapshotRecordArray)  {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.set(`toLoad.${type}`, { resolve, reject });
      Ember.run.debounce(this, this.loadDebounces, 1);
    });
  },
});
```

You basically can just debounce multiple requests and process them as one. However this is not RESTFull nor JSONAPI compliant. Just to mention this.